# Адаптивная верстка bootstrap 4 проблема с 320px

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap4

Вопрос звучит так:
Как можно менять  через css при экране в 320px.

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container header__container">
   <div class="header__info">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 col-2">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 col-9">
      <h1>
       
      </h1>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-4 col-1">
      <a href="tel:"></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

css

```css
 @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
 . col-md-7 col-lg-6 col-8{
  @include make-col(8);
 }
 .header__info {
     padding-top: 3px;
     padding-bottom: 3px;
 }
 .header__info img {
  margin-right: -21px;
  height: 40px;
 }
 .header__info h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 6px;
 }
 .header__info a {
  margin-left: 15px;
     margin-right: 0;
     margin-top: 1px;
 }
 
nav {
 padding: 1px 0px 1px 13px;
}
ul {
 justify-content: space-between;
}
nav a {
 font-size: 9px;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 3px 0px 5px;
}



}
```

Как 
`<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 col-9">`

изменить к примеру на

`<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-6 col-8">`

в css при разрешении 320px.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В Bootstrap 4 при ширине <576px есть свой классовый префикс .col-
Например 
Либо через костыль присваивать

```
 @media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 320px)
```

И Ваша запись некорректна

```
. col-md-7 col-lg-6 col-8{@include make-col(8);}
```

Comment: . col-md-7 col-lg-6 col-9{@include make-col(8);}

Comment: Так будет коректна

Comment: Не работает @media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 320px)